# how i can change the normal RestApi into http post request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How i can change the normal RestApi into http post request in angularjs?

I want to send this url as $http - post request in angularjs in function.

http://localhost:3001/ams/v2/folder?name=SampleCCCCCC

my code:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3001/ams/v2/folder?name=SampleCCCCCC', data, config)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Server request is sending");
})
.error(function(data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("Server request is NoT sending");
});
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Error: data is not defined
$scope.ok@http://localhost:3000/app/components/assetmanagement/controllers/library.FolderCreation.js:76:6
anonymous/fn@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js line 13275 > Function:2:194
@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:478:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15922:16
```

But, it is not working. Any idea Please?

Comment: have given any thought to actually ... doing a google search ?

Comment: @sirrocco: I copied my code, this is what I tried..

Comment: @User123 - whats the error you are getting in console?

Comment: ok, now show what `data` is.`

Comment: @ManojShevate: I pasted the error console string on my post, Could you please see that?

Comment: @User123 - looking at error it seems data variable is not defined. could you please share entire javascript used here like what is the value of data and config variable defined in your code?

Comment: @ManojShevate: Its bulk of code and i am not able to separate, I am just asking, Could you please give me exact $http post request for above url? So that, I can make it out...

Comment: @User123 Just a suggestion and some info: the `.success` and `.error` functions in the [`$http` service are deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in the most recent versions of AngularJS.  Instead you should use `.then`: such as... `$http.post('someUrl', data, config).then(function success(response) { ... }, function error(response) { ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to folow this example.

```js
var $scope = {};
var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/ams/v2/folder?name=SampleCCCCCC';
var callData = {
  
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.postCallResponse = 'Post not done!';
  
  $scope.makeApiPostCall = function(){
    
    $http.post(apiUrl, callData)
    .then(
      function(res){ // SUCCESS
        $scope.postCallResponse = res;
      }
      ,function(res){ // ERROR
        $scope.postCallResponse = res;
      }
      ,function(res){ // FINALLY
        $scope.postCallResponse = res;
      }
    );
    
  }
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="makeApiPostCall()">Make POST call</button>
  <div ng-bind="postCallResponse"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is only sending http://localhost:3001/ams/v2/folder and it is not sending http://localhost:3001/ams/v2/folder?name=SampleCCCC

Comment: I've just edited my answer to use your entire URL with query params.